# localeCompare returns 0 for different unicode symbols

Tags: javascript, string, string-comparison

I am looking to use `localeCompare` for strictly sorting strings but I am finding it is  returning `0` when given two different unicode characters which erroneously indicates they are the same e.g.

ℜ   U+211C (alt-08476)  BLACK-LETTER CAPITAL R = real part

ℝ   U+211D (alt-08477)  DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL R = the set of real numbers

```js
"ℜ".localeCompare("ℝ", "en")   
> 0

"ℜ" === "ℝ"                    
> false

"ℜ".charCodeAt(0)
> 8476

"ℝ".charCodeAt(0)
> 8477
```

I have looked at the docs but the defaults are already for "sort" and "variant" which appear to be the strictest available:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator

Is `localeCompare` unable to give a strict a ordering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that after detecting that they are both non-ASCII versions of uppercase letter R, `String.localeCompare()` correctly specifies that there is no particular distinction in order between the two characters.

```js
console.log(
  // two non-0x43 uppercase Cs
  'ℂ'.localeCompare('', 'en'),

  // two non-0x5A uppercase Zs
  "ℤ".localeCompare('', 'en'),
  
  // 0x5A ASCII Z precedes both:
  "Z".localeCompare('ℤ', 'en'),
  "Z".localeCompare('', 'en'),
);
```

You can use unicode position in places where there is no defined sort order due to canonical equivalence:

```js
const sort = (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b) || -(a < b);

console.log(
  //  1 (C <  in localeCompare)
  sort('', 'C'),
  // -1 (Canonically equivalent; falls back to 0x2102 < 0xD835)
  sort('ℂ', '')  
);
```

From the [ECMAScript spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.9):

> The actual return values are implementation-defined to permit
> implementers to encode additional information in the value, but the
> function is required to define a total ordering on all Strings and to
> **return 0 when comparing Strings that are considered [canonically
> equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)** by the Unicode standard.

From the Wikipedia article on Unicode equivalence:

> Unicode provides two such notions, canonical equivalence and
> compatibility. Code point sequences that are defined as canonically
> equivalent are assumed to have the same appearance and meaning when
> printed or displayed.
>
> For example, the code point **U+006E** (the Latin
> lowercase **n**) followed by **U+0303** (the combining tilde **◌̃**) is
> defined by Unicode to be canonically equivalent to the single code
> point U+00F1 (the lowercase letter **ñ** of the Spanish alphabet).
>
> Therefore, **those sequences should be displayed in the same manner**,
> should be treated in the same way by applications such as
> **alphabetizing names** or searching, and may be substituted for each
> other. Similarly, each Hangul syllable block that is encoded as a
> single character may be equivalently encoded as a combination of a
> leading conjoining jamo, a vowel conjoining jamo, and, if appropriate,
> a trailing conjoining jamo.

[image: Unicode equivalence example.]

See also: https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/

Comment: @JonasWilms Good link, added it!